# how to check page load if i have more than 50 pages

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

I am new to selenium webdriver (java coding). I have been given a website and asked to write script to check if all the pages load properly.I was not sure how to check a page load. One of my friend suggested that when a page load, i should look for last element which gets loaded and use a wait method on that element to check until its visible.

My question is I have more than 50 pages to check. For each page should i use a wait method and check visibility, becoz it takes a lot of time . Is there any other way?

Comment: if you need to check the whole 50 pages then that is the only way.. Normally you have check whether the content showing on the Page is correct..

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by following the steps given below (for all 50 pages, one at a time):

1. Identify an element which is displayed at last in the browser rendering.
2. Add `visibility_of_element_located`, to check whether the element is displayed on the web page or not.

Wait for visibility of an element:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")) # here, you can use any available locator of your choice, like, By.XPATH, BY.CLASS_NAME etc.
```

> This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException or if it finds that the element is displayed, will return it in 0 - 10 seconds. WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully. A successful return is for ExpectedCondition type is Boolean return true or not null return value for all other ExpectedCondition types.

So, you are not actually waiting for `10 seconds` to check whether the element is displayed. Once the element is displayed on the page, the method will return immediately within `10 seconds`.

**Note:** `10 seconds` is configurable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in **visual testing** direction, and pure selenium not designed for that.

You may try two addons for Selenium:

1) Applitools (https://applitools.com/), cloud based, you could try it for free,
examples is here https://eyes.applitools.com/app/Web/Deploy/Tutorial/tutorial.html

2) Or you could use Sikuli(http://www.sikuli.org/), free, non cloud.